# Python How to print the text read from a file without the escape char?

Tags: python, string

The python code is like this. I try to read the data from a file. But when I print it I get the output with `square bracket` and `escape char`. If I just print the content which I copy from the data file. It show normally. 
The result is like this: 
`[u'\n\n\xefhello']`

How to fix this problem.
This is the result window. I try to remove the `square bracket` but it doesn't work. And I try to encode the string by `utf-8`, neither working.

And the type str I read from the data file is `<type 'unicode'>`.

[20161212185023.bmp](http://7xpvdr.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/20161212185023.bmp)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

f = open('sgsres.txt', 'r')
content = f.read()
cleantext = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml").text
cleantext = re.sub('[\[\]]', '', cleantext)
print cleantext
```

--- **update**---
@Boris

I rewrite the code according to your answer but the the output I get is like this. 
Every char output on a single line and the escape char seems still print out as raw text.
[20161212193059.bmp](http://7xpvdr.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/20161212193059.bmp)

---**update**---

This question is fixed when I encode the string with `acsii` and ignore the error like this.
`text = text.encode('ascii',errors='ignore')`

But I still don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

`Square brackets` indicate that you are working with a `list`.

As for the `string`s that are inside that `list`, this is what you can do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

f = open('sgsres.txt', 'r')
content = f.read()
cleantext = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml").text
for item in cleantext:
    item = item.strip()
    print item
```